# Open links in private browsing (incognito) window automatically in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, private-browsing

Is there a way (except click-right → *Open Link in Incognito Window*) to make Google Chrome open all links in an incognito window from normal browsing mode?

Comment: I wrote a small Chrome plugin to add this short-cut to Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/key-ncognito/lilomadmkegmkmkjmdbbgalimcmfogfk

Comment: @Nixphoe No, the OP is asking how to open a link from a normal browser window in incognito, not how to open Chrome in incognito mode.

Answer (score 24):

Right click on the link, and then press the letter "g" on the keyboard.
It's almost as fast as just clicking the link

Comment: This does not work on macOS.

Comment: @slhck I played around until I found it, for macOS, it's: right click -> 'n' -> 'enter'.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if you can suddenly switch all links to open in incognito mode, but extensions like [Ghost Incognito](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ghost-incognito/gedeaafllmnkkgbinfnleblcglamgebg?hl=en-US) will ensure that some links always open in incognito mode, this defeats the purpose of incognito mode.
[incognito button](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/incognito-button/bjgmlhfigmdgbknineiakhgobgnhhkab?hl=en-US)  and [Incognito Tab switch](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/incognito-tab-switch/ofeampmlffjabmpdebckhpmcjkcjkahi?hl=en-US) will help you switch your current tabs to incognito mode.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> + Click on Link

Figured this out by just playing around with chrome

Comment: Could you source this? I've read both the [Windows](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en) and [Linux](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/171571?hl=en&ref_topic=25799) Chrome keyboard shortcuts and found nothing in regards to that shortcut. Could you be using an extension to that effect?

Comment: Sorry, but it’s not working for me. Not on Mac anyway.

Comment: I did not know about this. Very useful thanks, +1

Comment: Not working for me. Alt+shift+click on link just opened in a new window same as what Shift+click would do.

Comment: Does not work on OS X...

Comment: Doesn't work for me I'm afraid

Comment: This is incorrect.  It should be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> + Click on Link, or <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> + Click on Link (on a Mac).

Comment: cmd-shift-click does not work for me on sierra, chrome current as of today.

Comment: Doesn't work ...

Comment: Doesn't work for me either

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I wanted to do the same thing and could not find the answer anywhere so I decided to post my solution.

Note that all links launched from a shell command will be in incognito, original chrome desktop shortcut etc still launch chrome in  standard mode.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\" --incognito -- \"%1\" "
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the other variation on this thread first but that didn't work... 
Here is what worked on my machine.

I'm on Windows 10 Pro, v.1903

Using RegEdit, I changed:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command]
From: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -- "%1"
To: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --incognito -- "%1"
```

Double-clicking .url file now opens it in private mode :-) Thanks [bwDraco](https://superuser.com/users/73918/bwdraco)!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

This sadly no longer works. I tried every single key and couldn't find one that replaced <kbd>n</kbd>. So I don't think this works as of March 2024.

On macOS,

1. Right click the link
2. Press <kbd>n</kbd>
3. Press <kbd>enter</kbd>

Answer (score -2):

First create shortcut of Google chrome in desktop. Then Rename that shortcut to any convenient name like: **new chrome**.

Then Right click on shortcut and select **properties**. You will see a **Shortcut** menu there. In the shortcut menu, go to **Target** field and add **--incognito** at end of the path. But make sure there is a space between double quote and dash.

Now open this shortcut chrome and you will see that your incognito chrome is ready.

Hope this will help you.
Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

Hope this will work...

1. Create a Shortcut on Desktop for the browser (like chrome)
2. Update link in properties with '--incognito' in the end.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that a shortcut on the desktop will affect what happens when the user clicks on a link in a web page in a browser window?   Have you ever done it?

Comment: my bad, I read that article as per my requirements,
but It's not possible otherwise,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148136/how-can-we-open-a-link-in-private-browsing-mode#16148152